# git-tf: checkin a commit which moves a file from a folder which is to be deleted

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I'm running into a problem checking in a particular commit using git-tf.  The problematic commit involves moving (renaming) a file which is a child of a folder which is to be deleted.  Apparently this is a no-no in TFS (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116482/tfs-2010-deleting-a-folder-in-visual-studio-solution-before-check-in-of-change)).

In the future, I will obviously try to avoid doing this in a single commit on the git side.  But since I've already made this error, I need to figure out a way around it to get the git-tf checkin to work.  I'm relatively new to git, so maybe there's a simple solution.  Seems like I need to somehow go back and "split" the offending commit into two parts: one where the file is moved/renamed out of the folder, and one where the folder is deleted.  Or maybe there's something I can do on the TFS side to make it happy.

The error TFS is throwing is as follows:
TF14060: The item $/blah/... cannot be deleted.  One or more children have pending changes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the helpful folks at codeplex:

> To get past this error you can try the following
>
> git tf checkin --renamemode=justFiles
>
> What this will do is that it will rename the files that need to be
>   renamed but leave the empty folders behind in TFS.

This did the trick for me.  As promised, this option left behind an empty folder on the TFS side.  I was able to delete the folder on TFS and then do a "git-tf pull" without any further issue.

Comment: Note: If you're using **git tfs** (and not git tf) then you should instead update to version 0.17.1 or newer. That should solve that problem.

Comment: I'm seeing it with git tfs 0.25.1.0.

Comment: I've had the exact same issue in 0.27.0. To get around this I had to create a dummy file in the folder which was trying to be deleted. Then delete it in tfs once it had been checked in! :(